# Why is string not recognizing my output as an integer

Tags: python

```
balance = int(100)
balance *= 0.05 + balance
balance *= 0.05 + balance
balance *= 0.05 + balance
print (int(round ( balance, '.2f' )))
```

im trying to calculate what 100$ interest would be after 3 years compound interest.

I originally tried this

```
balance = 100
balance *= 0.05 + balance
balance *= 0.05 + balance
balance *= 0.05 + balance
print  (format( balance, '.2f' ))
```

but my formatting caused the answer to be in the trillions instead of a 5 digit float.

Comment: `print("{:.02f}".format( 100 * 1.05**3))` ?

Comment: What is your expected output (I imagine `115.76`) and the one you are actually getting? Also, as noted, you can calculate compounded interest much simpler.

Comment: @busybear , 10020115160330914.00 was the output i was getting on my original code. which way would you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

You're multiplying the balances.  Try this:

```
balance = int(100)
balance = balance * 0.05 + balance
balance = balance * 0.05 + balance
balance = balance * 0.05 + balance
print("{:.02f}".format(balance))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your operator precedence incorrect: the assignment operator is *last*.  Thus, what you've done is

```
balance = balance * (0.05 + balance)
```

Instead, try one of the canonical ways to express interest:

```
rate = 0.05
balance += balance * rate
```

or

```
balance *= (1 + rate)
```

The parentheses aren't needed, but will help you read this.

Also, you might make a parameter (variable) for your repetition:

```
limit = 3
for year in range(limit):
    balance *= 1 + rate

print("{:.02f}".format(balance))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to order of operations. `balance *= 0.05 + balance` will add `0.05` and `balance` before multiplying it to `balance`. What you'd want is `balance = balance + balance * 0.05` or `balance = balance * 1.05`.

You can create a function to calculate compound interest to make it easier:

```
def comp_int(balance, rate, years):
    return balance * (1 + rate)**years

balance = 100
rate = 0.05
years = 3
new_bal = comp_int(balance, rate, years)
print(f'{new_bal:.2f}')
```